# "I hacked my way into this interview": Is this a good idea for getting a job?

Tags: penetration-test, ethics, grey-hat

There's been some joking on the internet where a candidate would "hack their way into getting a job interview" and disclose that as a proof of skill in a job related to Infosec.

If I somehow find a "hack", such as keywords in an [ATS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicant_tracking_system), bypassing application checkpoints, secretly putting my name in the "interview list", or anything similar, would it be a good idea to disclose that along with a report on that hack as a reason to hire me for a job in Infosec?

From some quick research (such as [23946](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23946/consequences-of-grey-hat-hacking/23949#23949)), I'm guessing not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. [workplace.se] seems to be a better fit for this kind of questions. But in general I would say that cheating like this is not a good start of a career  because it kind of implies that you might continue to cheat to your advantage even after you've got hired. It might work for some specific jobs in some specific working environments though.

Comment: I would use this as a last resort or final bonus. If there's any doubt of your skill at the end of the interview, bringing proof of self-summoning would really make a worthy management hire you. It could also scare them if they are weak.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think The Workplace actually has a question about this exactly.

Answer (score 6):

Gaining access to a computer system without the consent of the owner is a violation of law in most countries (if not all of them). If it is your future employer, then I would guess it shows that you can not be trusted with confidentiality, on top of it being illegal.

Please don't do it.

If you want to show off your skill, then offer to take a test or get permission first. Make sure that whoever gave you permission actually has the rights to do so.